# How to display multiple shipping address in dropdown rather than boxes in Magento 2.1 C E?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

Please check the attached screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uydzU.png

and help me solve this please.

Comment: i did my self. i got it.

Comment: Can you tell me how can you solve

Comment: @Jagdish can you please share your solution

Answer (score 0):

We have check the same in **magento 2.x** shop system with multiple shipping address, and found that working fine.

Please **click the shipping address select box**, all the shipping address available in this select box. Please refer below mention Image.

[image]